# create one array after using map() twice

Tags: javascript, node.js

I may or may not get in 2 differently formatted bits of data.

They both need to be stripped of characters in different ways. Please excuse the variable names, I will make them better once I have this working.

```
  const cut = flatten.map(obj => {
    return obj.file.replace("0:/", "");
  });

  const removeDots = flatten.map(obj => {
    return obj.file.replace("../../uploads/", "");
  })
```

I then need to push the arrays into my mongo database.

```
let data;
for (const loop of cut) {
  data = { name: loop };
  product.images.push(data);
}
let moreData;
for (const looptwo of removeDots) {
  moreData = {name: looptwo};
  product.images.push(moreData);
}
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to either join them or do an if/else because the result of this is that if I have 2 records, it ends up duplicating and I get 4 records instead of 2. Also, 2 of the records are incorrectly formatted ie: the "0:/ is still present instead of being stripped away.

Ideally I would like have a check that if `0:/` is present, remove it, if `../../uploads/` is present or if both are present, remove both. And then create an array from that to push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your 2 replace on the same `map` :

```
const processed = flatten.map(obj => {
    return obj.file.replace("0:/", "").replace("../../uploads/", "");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the possible patterns, you can create a regex and use it to replace any occurrences.

```js
const regex = /(0:\/|(\.\.\/)+uploads\/)/g
const processed = flatten.map(obj => obj.file.replace(regex, ''));
```

You can verify [here](https://regex101.com/r/leY7hJ/1/)

---

Note, regex is a pattern based approach. So it has pros and cons.

**Pro:**

- You can have any number of folder nesting. Using string `../../uploads/` will restrict you with 2 folder structure only.
- You can achieve transformation in 1 operation and code looks clean.

**Cons:**

- Regex can be hard to understand and can reduce readability of code a bit. (*Opinionated*)
- If you have pattern like `.../../uploads/bla`, this will be parsed to `.bla`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask also about a possible way of joining two arrays, I'll give you couple of solutions (with and w/o joining).

You can either chain `.replace` on the elements of the array, or you can concat the two arrays in your solution. So, either:

```
const filtered = flatten.map(obj => {
    return obj.file.replace('0:/', '').replace('../../uploads/', '');
});
```

Or (joining the arrays):

```
// your two .map calls go here
const joinedArray = cut.concat(removeDots);
```

Comment: I like your answer but think it would be fair to accept ekans answer as he posted the first bit of your answer first. I appreciate your answer though, thank you.